# For progressive web apps, how can I specify which icon should appear on the splash screen?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA with an icon at 144 and 512. Both seem to appear in the application tab in chrome, but when the splash screen shows up the icon is really small (I think it's the 144 icon). Is there a way to specify which icon should be used for the splash screen? Will the splash screen always show the largest image?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend always having 192px as the minimum sized icon and create 3 other versions at 256px, 384px and 512px. However, if you want to ensure that the user is not downloading too much data for the splash screen, especially on a low density device then you can go lower and **Chrome** will try to fetch the most appropriate image.

Used to install to the homescreen is determined by using the largest icon found in one of the following `<link>` tags:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png">    (recommended)
<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
```

> ***Reference:***
>
> [Add to Homescreen - chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen)
>
> [Splash Screen for Installed Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen)